# How to read a huge xml file using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How can I read huge xml files (more than 1GB) using this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(file)
doc = tree.getroot()
abstracts = doc.findall('PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract')
for abstract in abstracts:
    abs_text = abstract.findall('AbstractText')
    ab = ''
    for txt in abs_text:
        ab += txt.text
    collections.col_pubmed_xmls.insert({'text': ab, 'tag': tag})
```

after executing this code an error says that file can not be openned in this line:

```
 ET.parse(file)
```

I can read small files using this code.
What to do?

Comment: is everything fine with the file? existing/validation... and use xml.etree.cElementTree ....20/15 time faster Jeegar

Comment: @AriGold Yes! I'm iterating through the directory, so file exists. I've downloaded the file from a valid source.

Comment: What is the exact error including the complete traceback? You are not iterating through the directory in the code you've shown. In fact `file` appears out of thin air, so this isn't a runnable example. If the file exists there could still be a permission problem or if it is Windows another process already has this file opened.